# Matplotlib: ax.annotate from each item in the list separating by newline

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I create list of items `proteinlabel`

```
proteinlabel = ['K{} - {}\nsum: {:.2e} mean: {:.2e}\n'.format(i+1, name, Harea.sum(), Harea.mean()) 
              for i, (name, Harea) in enumerate(zip(uniprot_label, prot_nHarea))]

print proteinlabel
OUT>> ['K1 - Albumin, Recombinant human\nsum: 1.00e+12 mean: 3.70e+06\n', 'K2 - Antithrombin III from plasma\nsum: 9.36e+11 mean: 5.20e+06\n', 'K3 - Annexin V from human placenta\nsum: 6.79e+11 mean: 6.85e+06\n']
```

I would like to print this in subplot box by `ax.annotate` with the newline as defined but the list is printed exactly like at `OUT>>` shown, `\n` does not work as newline .

```
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((8, 10), (6, 0), rowspan=2, colspan=4)
ax2.annotate( proteinlabel, xy=(0.5, 0.5))
```

[image]

How to print each item in the list separating by newline by `ax.annotate` (or any other better ways) in the subplot box? Like

```
K1 - Albumin, Recombinant human
sum: 1.00e+12 mean: 3.70e+06
K2 - Antithrombin III from plasma
sum: 9.36e+11 mean: 5.20e+06
K3 - Annexin V from human placenta
sum: 6.79e+11 mean: 6.85e+06
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the list as text, not the text itself. So first make the list a string, then it can be interpreted correctly.

```
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((8, 10), (6, 0), rowspan=2, colspan=4)
ax2.annotate( "".join(proteinlabel) , xy=(0.5, 0.5))
```